# Unity3D load an not exist DLL file , still work but no effect to the result

Tags: c#, dll, mono, unity-game-engine

I tried to integrate my own c++ plugin with Unity3D project. But it doesn't work. So i wrote some small code to test, I found some strange problems, make me #$%#@$^@#$^#^

First I create a small dll project by code

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)

extern "C"
{


        EXPORT_API void testFloatPoint(float *mFloat)
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i<13;i++)
            {
                *mFloat = (float)i;
                mFloat++;
            }
            mFloat = mFloat-13;
        }
}
```

Then I tried to invoke this dll file in unity3D c# script by following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
public class TestDLL : MonoBehaviour 
{
    float[] pose_float;//   
    #region import c++ dll 
    [DllImport ("TestDLL2")]
    public static extern  void  testFloatPoint ([In,Out] float[] pose_float);    
    #endregion 

        void Start ()
        {
                     pose_float = new float[13]; 
             testFloatPoint(pose_float);
             print ("get pose_float data!!!");
             for(int i=0;i<13;i++)
             {
                    print(pose_float[i]);
             }
                }
}
```

but the print out msg are all zero. It's a bit strange, because before I got the result is "0,1,2,3....12". I can't figure out where the problem is . So i tried to remove the dll file from my unity3D project folder. Much more strange problem is, it can still run with all zero output result. There is no TestDLL2 file under the project folder and there is no dllnotfound problem. 
Is there some advice from U? It bother me around one week , Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you running this from the editor?  Unity editor [doesn't unload dlls](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/293867/easier-way-to-handle-unloading-dlls.html?sort=oldest) if you run your app from preview.  At least it didn't in 3.5.7.  I've not tested in 4.#

Comment: Hi, Jerdak, I run this inside Unity editor.